# Set a property value from different feature and different property value with filtering in same featurecollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to set a feature property value from different feature and different property in same feature collection.

Each point has ID (Point ID), SUB_P_ID (sub point ID), LC_ID (class ID is) and SUB_P_LC_ID(sub point LC ID).

I want to set sub point class ID (LC_ID) to parent feature SUB_P_LC_ID field.

In map function, I get SUB_P_ID value, than i want to filter it with field(ID) and get LC_ID, then set LC_ID value to feature SUB_P_LC_ID property.

In map function, i can't get filtered feature.

This code gives error:

The result must be:

{ID: 101, SUB_P_ID: 201,LC_ID: 1,SUB_P_LC_ID: 2}

{ID: 201, SUB_P_ID: 201,LC_ID: 2,SUB_P_LC_ID: 3}

{ID: 202, SUB_P_ID: 203,LC_ID: 1,SUB_P_LC_ID: 4}

```
var points = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(12.88227, 52.52504), {ID: 101, SUB_P_ID: 201,LC_ID: 1,SUB_P_LC_ID: 0}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(12.89514, 52.50953), {ID: 201, SUB_P_ID: 202,LC_ID: 2,SUB_P_LC_ID: 0}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(12.91718, 52.51058), {ID: 202, SUB_P_ID: 203,LC_ID: 3,SUB_P_LC_ID: 0})
];

var FC = ee.FeatureCollection(points);

print(FC)

var newList = FC.map(function(feature){
  var index = feature.get('SUB_P_ID')
  var filtered = FC.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ID', index)).first()
  var n_sub_p_id = filtered.get('LC_ID')
  return feature.set('SUB_P_LC_ID', n_sub_p_id)
  })

print('newList', newList)
```

Comment: I'm not very good with GEE, but I spent a few minutes trying to figure out the source of the problem. I think that your problem stems from `var n_sub_p_id = filtered.get('LC_ID')`. When I break up your `newList` line by line and print the vars created, I get your error with printing that line. `filtered` seems to be a `Feature` and thus you should probably be able to get the `Property` from it, but it returns "NULL" when I `print(filtered)`. I have no idea why.

Comment: Thank you John...